# Silly shell script error

Tags: shell

I've got the following shell script for OSX I want to use to correct/fix permissions for a user directory, but am getting the error:

```
bash-3.2# sh fix-perms.sh 
fix-perms.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
fix-perms.sh: line 23: `else'
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Script fixes permissions in Users directory

#  Set PATH as shortcut
#
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

# First verify volume is mounted before executing

if [ -d /Volumes/UserStorage ] ;
then

        USERS=`mktemp -t users-XXXXX.log`
        ls -1 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users > $USERS

        for i in `cat $USERS`; do
        chmod -R 700 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i

        find /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i -type d -exec chmod 701 {} \;
        exit 0

else

echo Volume Not Mounted

exit 1

fi
```

It's got to be something silly/stupid that I'm missing but darned if I can see it!

Thanks for your tips/insight in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `done` in your `for` loop. The syntax is:

```
for statement
do
  statements...
done
```

Comment: Ah yes, that was the problem. But how can I keep my exit status once the loop if finished without breaking it?

Comment: @Doug: I am not sure what you mean. `exit 0` will terminate the whole script. I'd guess that you want to put `exit 0` __after__ `done`...

Comment: Vlad, yup, the echo needed to follow the 'done'. All good now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Q: Do you realize you're missing "done" in your do loop?

Q: What happens if you put "then" on the same line as your semicolon?

Here are some more examples:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/

Here is your original code, slightly modified:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script fixes permissions in Users directory
#  Set PATH as shortcut
#
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

# First verify volume is mounted before executing
if [ -d /Volumes/UserStorage ] ; then
        USERS=`mktemp -t users-XXXXX.log`
        ls -1 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users > $USERS

        for i in `cat $USERS`; do
          chmod -R 700 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i

          find /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i -type d -exec chmod 701 {} \;
          exit 0
        done

else
  echo Volume Not Mounted
  exit 1
fi
```